# How use valgrind to check memory leak of docker when called via docker-compose

Tags: docker, memory, memory-leaks, docker-compose, valgrind

I would like to check for potential memory leaks of a number of containers running via `docker-compose` and a `YAML` file.

When `valgrind` is called using the following command:

`valgrind --log-file=/tmp/debug.log \
         --trace-children=yes \
         --track-origins=yes docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build -d`

the `valgrind` stops tracing when the `docker-compose` finishes with setting up the containers; it does not trace the `docker` calls that `docker-compose` has performed.

Is there a way to make `valgrind` continue to check the memory activity of the `docker` when it is called via `docker-compose`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible because the `docker` calls (like `run`) are in fact sent over a socket as *commands* (`/var/run/docker.sock`). Then, those *commands* are in fact run by the docker daemon, which is a different process, already started when you run  `valgrind ...`.

What you can do is to install `valgrind` inside the container itself and make sure that it starts the main process, by replacing the `CMD` command.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to modify the `docker.service` file so that the `valgrind` starts with `docker` daemon itself?

Comment: @imriss I never tried it, but I don't see how it would help you to monitor the daemon and all it starts

Comment: @imriss you could try to install `valgrind` inside the container